# How can I avoid "Open cursor limit exceeded" error for this code?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, ado.net, plsql

```
foreach (string num in ld2.Keys)
{
  double state;
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < states.Count; i++)
  {
    cmd = mdb.getCommand("select value V " +
                         "  from TAB_CHART_DATA " + 
                         " where TIMESTAMP = (select max(TIMESTAMP) " +
                         "                      from TAB_CHART_DATA " + 
                         "                     where chart_type= " + chart_type + 
                         "                       and upper(upper(state)) = '" + states[i] + "' " +
                         "                       and CSIS_ID = " + CSISPID + 
                         "                       and baselinecode like '" + num + "'" +
                         "                   ) " +
                         "   and chart_type = " + chart_type + 
                         "   and upper(state) = '" + states[i] + "' " +
                         "   and CSIS_ID = " + CSISPID + 
                         "   and baselinecode like '" + num + "'"
                        );

    state = mdb.ExecSQLAndGetFirstInt(cmd);
  }

}
```

This loop runs for more than 3000 times.

Comment: Please show us the real code. Are you maybe creating a new statement each time in the loop and not closing it?

Comment: Whatever `ExecSQLAndGetFirstInt` is doing, it should close the reader it uses to retrieve the data.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name- Yes it closes the reader.

Comment: does closing the reader mean that the cursor is closed?

Comment: Your code is open to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetch all rows in one query and loop over the result set in your code instead of opening cursors and killing the database.

Comment: I want to use the result of the query for further fetches.

Comment: @laksh - Please post the complete code and explain _exactly_ what you are trying to do (edit your question and add the details to it).