# How can I close implicit cursor Forcibly?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Getting the reference of the automatically generated cursor to close it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I avoid "Open cursor limit exceeded" error for this code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286114/how-can-i-avoid-open-cursor-limit-exceeded-error-for-this-code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't. From Oracle's [PL/SQL docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/static.htm#i46192):

> An implicit cursor is a session cursor that is constructed and managed by PL/SQL. PL/SQL opens an implicit cursor every time you run a SELECT or DML statement. **You cannot control an implicit cursor**, but you can get information from its attributes.

You have a full control over [explicit cursors](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/static.htm#CIHCAHJA).

Comment: Does creation of  one explicit cursor avoid creation of implicit cursor by PL/SQL.

Comment: No.  Cursors are how information is pulled from Oracle.  Implict cursors are a good thing, in that you don't need to explicitly manage them.

Comment: @laksh, yes it will prevent oracle opening an implicit cursor as you will have opened an explicit cursor.